# How to filter out incorrect records?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I try to filter a `RDD` using some condition exception generated due to bad record. I want to ignore those record don't want to capture too. So, how can I add a try block when I use filter method?

```
scala> val newRDD = mysc1.filter(_(3) == "NS3")
newRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] 
                      = MapPartitionsRDD[12] at filter at <console>:28
scala> newRDD.take(10)
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular instance, it could be as simple as

```
mysc1.filter(arr => (arr.length > 3) && (arr(3) == "NS3"))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mysc1.flatMap(x => Try(x(3)).filter(_ == "NS3").map(_ => x).toOption)
```

or even better using `Array` as `PartialFuntion`

```
mysc1.flatMap(x => x.lift(3).filter(_ == "NS3").map(_ => x))
```

with for comperehension

```
mysc1.flatMap(x => for(y <- Try(x(3)).toOption if y == "NS3") yield x)
```

and

```
mysc1.flatMap(x => for(y <- x.lift(3) if y == "NS3") yield x)
```

and finally full `for` version

```
val newRDD = for {
  x <- mysc1
  y <- x.lift(3) if y == "NS3"
} yield x
```

Comment: Thanks you it is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> def filterFn[A](array: Array[A], valueToMatch: A): Boolean = array match {
     |   case Array(_, _, x, _*) if x == valueToMatch => true
     |   case _                                       => false
     | }
filterFn: [A](array: Array[A], valueToMatch: A)Boolean

scala> filterFn(Array(1,2,3), 3)
res2: Boolean = true

scala> filterFn( Array(), "foobar" )
res4: Boolean = false
```

Then, you could do something like:

`mysc1.filter(xs => filterFn(xs, "NS3") )`